# Problem with invalid regular expression missing / (slash)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, regex

I have a [spreadsheet](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2F1q2CZA8cr1TfBY5Qp-XYJkEDETwRNjqJUufz_N57d0C4%2Fedit%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR2Q3mJPX7hUpGbR-1s9zGPFGDm-FJbI8ONgUftFJRJPfq4yrz8QyBji9oI%23gid%3D898289105&h=AT2iBdnmqw-OY6eTVnL_lX6jW6m8U93rPE_BBHNnxrAQOI7pZ-OYiIj-eKQJpP2638Q8JrDGv-u1V87AFHrMRL42IfVxrloNMwLqies8VNWdZK-NWWbEb9XuK1aAbG8kJrk). I want to send emails from the Apps Script.

The logic to send email as follows.

Only send 1 email to each unique value in Column A (Co Name) the content of the email will include data in all rows. Only send email where Column N value is "Y".

Expected result:

The script will only send 3 emails:

Email 1: This is to remind that the following house lease contract of "HCMC 1" has expired.

- Mr A - house lease expire on 11 Jul 2021
- Mr B - house lease expire on 11 Jul 2021

Email 2: This is to remind that the following house lease contract of "HCMC 4" has expired.

- Mr C - house lease expire on 11 Jul 2021

Email 3: This is to remind that the following house lease contract of "HCMC 5" has expired.

- Mr D - house lease expire on 11 Jul 2021

I have this script below but leads to error "Problem with invalid regular expression missing /". Please help me to correct it.

```
function HLReminderAtYE1(){
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  //declare the spreadsheet
var Sheet = SS.getSheetByName("Tax_Master");  //declare sheet name
var Range = Sheet.getDataRange(); //to set the range as array
var Values = Range.getDisplayValues(); //to get the value in the array 
 
let fvs = Values.filter(function (item) { return item[13] == "Y" }); // filter only housecontract to remind at year end
 
/*var templateText = SS.getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1).getValue();*/
 const uniqueClient = [];
const map = new Map();
var messageBody,mailto;
    for (const item of fvs) { // create unique list
        if(!map.has(item[0])){
            map.set(item[0], true);    
            uniqueClient.push(item[0] );
        }
    } //end unique client create loop
    
    
    uniqueClient.forEach(function(client){ // loop through unique clients
       var messageList = [];
       fvs.forEach(function(row){ //loop through all rows to check for a match of unique client
        
          if(client == row[0]){
             messageList.push([row[1],row[7]]);
             const messageBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
                   messageBody.clientname = client;
             mailto =  row[12];
             htmlforemail = messageBody.evaluate().getContent();
            }
        }) // end inside matching row loop
        ;

            MailApp.sendEmail(
               mailto,          // email address
               client + "- House lease contract expire", // Subject line
               "",{htmlBody: htmlforemail}); 
    })// end unique client loop
}
```

I have the email template as follow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p> "Dear team,</p>
        <p> </p>
        <p> This is to notify that the house lease contract(s) of the below expats of <?= clientname ?> has expired. Please action accordingly.</p>
      </div>
      <div> 
       <? messageList.forEach(r=>{ ?> 
        
        
       <p> <?= r[1]?> house lease contract end on <?= r[2] ?> </p>
       <? })
      </div>
      <div>
          <p> ----------------- </p>
          <p> Sample email: </p>
          <p> Dear , </p>
          <p> </p>
          <p> The house lease contract(s) of the following expatriate employee(s) of <?= clientname ?> has expired. Please help provide us with the updated house lease contracts. Thank you.</p>
      <div>
        <p> </p>
        <p> Should you have any question, please contact us. </p>
        <p> </p>
        <p> Best regards, </p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error isn't related to regex (despite the error message) but to escaping of html in the template.

The reason of your issue is due to `<?=` of `<?= clientname ?>`. This is the format used in a [`Printing scriptlet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) but any escaping needs to be done in the Apps Script. *Contextual escaping is important if your script allows untrusted user input* but this is NOT the case in your script.

You need to use a [`Force-printing scriptlet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets); the syntax  looks like this `<?!= ... ?>`, or `<?!= clientname ?>`. This scriptlet doesn't allow user input; it contains all of the HTML or scripts that you want to insert exactly as specified.

---

**HTML**

Delete the existing HTML and substitute this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p> Dear team,</p>
        <p> </p>
        <p> This is to notify that the house lease contract(s) of the below expats of <?!= clientname ?> has expired. Please action accordingly.</p>
      </div>
      <div>      
       <p> <?!= assignee?> house lease contract end on <?!= contractenddate ?> </p>
      </div>
      <div>
          <p> ----------------- </p>
          <p> Sample email: </p>
          <p> Dear , </p>
          <p> </p>
          <p> The house lease contract(s) of the following expatriate employee(s) of <?!= clientname ?> has expired. Please help provide us with the updated house lease contracts. Thank you.</p>
      <div>
        <p> </p>
        <p> Should you have any question, please contact us. </p>
        <p> </p>
        <p> Best regards, </p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**SCRIPT**

Delete `messageList.push([row[1],row[7]]);`

Add two new lines after `messageBody.clientname = client;`

- `messageBody.assignee = row[1];`
- `messageBody.contractenddate = row[7];`

You'll note that `assignee` and `contractenddate` are both used in the html.

credit; @Tanaike identified this issue in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61153986/1330560) on StackOverflow.